# Parse to string for data before sending request

Tags: javascript, typescript, date

I know the data before sending will be parsed to string from any type. So where is this process done and how does it happen?
I had this question when I had a problem regarding the format for a Date type in javascript. Specifically, I want to send data that has a field of type Date and I want to format it before sending (example: 29-12-2022). However, I always get a result like `2022-12-29T17:00:00.000Z`.
I can convert the interface of data from Date to String. However, I don't want to do that

Comment: It's converted from Date object to string when encoding into JSON or added to URL as query parameter

Comment: Oh, Can you tell me more about where the conversion takes place?

Comment: When casting to string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use functions provived default by Date class:

1. Use [toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString#syntax) function

```js
const d = new Date();
let text = d.toLocaleDateString();
console.log(text);
```

2. Manually concatenate date, month, year strings:

```js
let d = new Date();
let mm = d.getMonth() + 1;
let dd = d.getDate();
let yy = d.getFullYear();
console.log(`${dd}-${mm}-${yy}`);
```